# Garbage collection for vector of object in PyO3

Tags: python, rust, garbage-collection, pyo3

I have 2 pyclasses `Block` and `BlockGroup`.

```
#[pyclass]
struct Block {
    start: i32,
    stop: i32,
}

#[pyclass]
struct BlockGroup {
    blocks: Vec<Block>
}
```

I'm new to PyO3 and I have read the [documentation](https://pyo3.rs/master/class.html#garbage-collector-integration) about garbage collection but I don't completely grok it.

> If your type owns references to other python objects, you will need to
>   integrate with Python's garbage collector so that the GC is aware of
>   those references.

Given that `BlockGroup` owns concrete `Block` objects, do I need to implement custom garbage collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `Block` and `Vec<Block>` respectively are part of rust's memory and not python's memory, so you don't need to worry about garbage collection. A object in python's memory would e.g. be `Py<Block>`.